# mysql, iterate through column names

Tags: sql, mysql

I would like to get all of the column names from a MySQL table, loop through each column name and then run a stored procedure using those column names as a variable.  Something to the effect of:

```
colnames = get column names from table

for each colname
  if something changed then
    do something
  else
    do something else
```

It looks like `SHOW COLUMNS FROM myTable` will give me the column names, but how would I get the column names into a loop?

I would really like to run all of this in a stored procedure using native SQL.  Since I'm still learning the intricacies of MySQL, and this would really help out my project.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: I just want to write this as native SQL from within MySQL workbench.  I was planning to use the column name as part of an UPDATE query.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
DECLARE col_names CURSOR FOR
  SELECT column_name
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  WHERE table_name = 'tbl_name'
  ORDER BY ordinal_position;


select FOUND_ROWS() into num_rows;

SET i = 1;
the_loop: LOOP

   IF i > num_rows THEN
        CLOSE col_names;
        LEAVE the_loop;
    END IF;


    FETCH col_names 
    INTO col_name;     

     //do whatever else you need to do with the col name

    SET i = i + 1;  
END LOOP the_loop;
```

Comment: That looks like exactly what I am after.  Thanks so much!  The first SELECT statement works, however, I am getting hung up with a syntax error when I add "DECLARE col_names CURSOR FOR".  Any thoughts as to why?

Comment: OK!  Turns out I just needed to change the delimiter and declare the num_rows, i, col_name and it works great.  Thanks so much!

Comment: And also needs to `open col_names;`.

Answer (score 6):

You can write a query against information_schema to get the column names:

```
SELECT column_name
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  WHERE table_name = 'tbl_name'
  ORDER BY ordinal_position
```

The column names are then returned just as any data from a table would be.

Comment: That's an excellent start to give me the column names!  How would I put those into a variable (list?) to iterate over those, though?