# loop through column names and insert values

Tags: mysql

I need help in looping through columns and inserting values to columns.

My Obj:- Insert new value to selective columns in a table using stored-procedure
i am using case statement to make selective choice and loop through to update list of columns

### My code:

```
  DELIMITER $$
  USE `test`$$
  DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `loopcolnm1`$$
  CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `loopcolnm1`()

  BEGIN
  DECLARE sColName  VARCHAR(255);
  DECLARE sEgStr  VARCHAR(255);
  DECLARE X  INT;
  SET segstr = ' ';
  SET X = 0;
  Loop_label : LOOP 
  IF  X > 9 THEN LEAVE  loop_label;
  END  IF;
  SET X = X+1;
  CASE 
        WHEN X= 1 THEN  
        SET sColName = 'age' ;
        WHEN X= 2 THEN  SET sColName  = 'Gender' ;
        WHEN X= 3 THEN  SET sColName  = 'incm_rng' ;
        WHEN X= 4 THEN  SET sColName  = 'Prc_rng' ;
        WHEN X= 5 THEN  SET sColName  = 'prop_purp';
        WHEN X= 6 THEN  SET sColName  = 'time_rng'  ;
        WHEN X= 7 THEN  SET sColName  = 'time_rsn' ;
        WHEN X= 8 THEN  SET sColName = 'crrnt_dmcl' ;
        WHEN X= 9 THEN  SET sColName  = 'Prop_Rsn' ;
        ELSE  SET sColName  = '\'All\' as Sub_Crit';

  END CASE ;
  SET sEgStr = CONCAT(sEgstr,' ',X, ' ',',' ,sColName, ' '); -- test variable

  INSERT INTO lptable (sColName) 
  VALUE ( CONCAT('loop + ',X));

  END LOOP; 
  SELECT segstr AS cnct;
      END$$

  DELIMITER ;
```

alternatively i tried with a similar [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4950252/mysql-iterate-through-column-names) but,  on both instance i get error

*edit(1) - Additional Information*

when i compile the stored procedure it does not throw up any error message however when i call the stored procedure

```
CALL loopcolnm1();
```

> Error Code: 1054 Unknown column 'sColName' in 'field list'

i am new to mysql, i am not sure if this is something that i can do or i am erring in syntax, kindly help

Comment: I don't see `col_name` anywhere in your code, I don't see how that function could be getting that error.

Comment: When you want to execute dynamic SQL, you have to use `PREPARE`

Comment: You can only insert whole rows into a table.  Also, the normal INSERT statement uses the keyword VALUES, not VALUE.  And the column-name is specified before the VALUES clause: `INSERT INTO TableName(ColumnName1, ColumnName2, ...) VALUES(Value1, Value2, ...)`.

Comment: Thank you Barmar, your guidance helped, i am now able to run the code without any issues,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your insert statement is wrong. You can't use a variable `sColName` directly as a column name. You should generate the `INSERT` query string by concatenating parts of strings.

This is wrong:

```
INSERT INTO lptable (sColName) VALUE ( CONCAT('loop + ',X));
```

And You have to use `VALUES` but not `VALUE`.

And you also need prepared statement to execute dynamically composed SQL statements.

You would need following changes in your procedure.

```
BEGIN  
   ...

    DECLARE table_fields_str     VARCHAR( 255 );
    DECLARE values_str           VARCHAR( 255 );
    DECLARE _temp_sql_insert_str VARCHAR( 255 );

   SET table_fields_str = CONCAT( 'INSERT INTO lptable (', sColName, ') ' );
   SET values_str       =  CONCAT( ' VALUES( CONCAT( ''loop '', ', X, ' ) )' );

   SELECT CONCAT( table_fields, values_str ) INTO @_temp_sql_insert_str;

   PREPARE stmt FROM @_temp_sql_insert_str;
   EXECUTE stmt;
END;
```

Comment: Ravinder, this is brilliant stuff... thank you for educating me You just made my new year day merrier :)