# Query first, then randomize, and then retrieve remaining fields

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table with about 70 columns and 120,000 rows of data. What I want to do is randomize a record and then displaying the values of others columns of this record.
If I do fetch all data,

```
$result=mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT id, column1, column2, column3, ..., column 70 from table');
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
  $info[] = array('id'=>$row['id'], 'column1'=>$row['column1'], ...); 
}
$randindex = rand(0,count($info));
$id = $info[$randindex]['id'];
echo $info[$randindex]['column1']; echo $info[$randindex]['column2']; ....
```

I'm afraid that this will significantly slow down the process. So I want to query only the ID before randomization, and then use the randomized ID to retrieve the other values of that record in the database.

```
$result=mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT id from table');
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
  $info[] = $row['id']; 
}
$randindex = rand(0,count($info));
$id = $info[$randindex];
```

and then retrieve all other fields of this particular record somehow. I asked how to do this in SQL [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38408365/reversed-query-sql) but I would like to know if there is any more efficient way by other means besides SQL. Do I need to do a loop like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4950252/mysql-iterate-through-column-names)?

Comment: You want to do something yourself better than the database.. hmm. Is there a particular reason for you not to want all the columns at once, but instead run 2 queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `ORDER BY RAND()` directly in the sql query:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

`ORDER BY RAND()` actually makes random order of you rows, and then you just do `LIMIT 1` in order to get only one row, the first one.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, do the following:

```
select min(id) as minid, max(id) as maxid
from table;
```

Then use php to generate a random `id` and do:

```
select t.*
from table t
where t.id >= $randid
order by id
limit 1;
```

With an index on `id` -- and reasonable assumptions about there not being too large gaps in the values -- then this will work well.

You can do the same thing in just one query:

```
select t.*
from table t cross join
     (select min(id) as minid, max(id) as maxid from table) tt
where t.id >= minid + rand() * (tt.maxid - tt.minid)
order by id
limit 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not think it is valid. I think it's faster  execute just one query with ORDER BY RAND ()