# How to update table using execute statement?

Tags: mysql, sql-update, execute

I have two tables (much simplified here):

QUADRI

```
ID SBR_750 b10C  TGI
---------------------
Q1    0      1    0
Q2    2      1    0
Q3    1      0    1
```

CELLE

```
CELLANAME NEEDED READY
----------------------
SBR_750    NULL   12
b10C       NULL   10
TGI        NULL    5
```

I want this result in CELLE:

```
CELLANAME NEEDED READY
------------------------
SBR_750     3     12
b10C        2     10
TGI         1      5
```

I tried to write a stored procedure but it doesn't works: ERROR 1210. Incorrect arguments to EXECUTE.

Here is the code:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%.zamberlan.local` PROCEDURE `AggiornaCelle`(IN nomecella varchar(15))
BEGIN
set @s='update celle set needed=(select sum(?) from quadri) where cellaname=?';
set @NC=nomecella;
prepare stmt from @s;
execute stmt using @NC;
deallocate prepare stmt;
END
```

UPDATE:
It doesn't work so I change strategy:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%.zamberlan.local` PROCEDURE `AggiornaCelle`()
BEGIN
declare i int;
declare num_rows int;
declare col_name varchar(20);
DECLARE col_names CURSOR FOR
  SELECT column_name
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  WHERE table_name = quadri
  ORDER BY ordinal_position;


select FOUND_ROWS() into num_rows;

SET i = 1;
the_loop: LOOP

   IF i > num_rows THEN
        CLOSE col_names;
        LEAVE the_loop;
    END IF;


    FETCH col_names 
    INTO col_name;     

     update celle set needed=sum(col_name) where cellaname=col_name;

    SET i = i + 1;  
END LOOP the_loop;
END
```

inspired by [mysql, iterate through column names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4950252/mysql-iterate-through-column-names).

However I receive the error "Cursor is not open..."

Comment: what is the logic? Why `SBR_750 = 3`?

Comment: the sum of Q1,Q2, Q3 in QUADRI

Answer (score 2):

You do need to use dynamic sql to do this. Celle knows about all the columns it needs from quadri so you could drive the creation of the dynamic statements from this fact. Using a cursor is as good a way to do it as any.

```
drop table if exists quadri;
create table quadri(ID varchar(2),SBR_750 int, b10C int, TGI int);
insert into quadri values
('Q1' ,   0 ,     1 ,   0),
('Q2' ,   2 ,     1 ,   0),
('Q3' ,   1 ,     0 ,   1);

drop table if exists celle;
create table CELLE (CELLANAME varchar(20) ,NEEDED int,READY int);
insert into celle values
('SBR_750'  ,  NULL ,  12),
('b10C'     ,  NULL ,  10),
('TGI'      ,  NULL ,   5);

drop procedure if exists `AggiornaCelle`;
delimiter $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `AggiornaCelle`()
begin
DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
declare col_name varchar(20);
declare cur1 CURSOR FOR 
 SELECT cellaname FROM celle ;

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

open cur1;
read_loop: loop
        fetch cur1 into col_name;
        if done then leave read_loop; end if;
        set @sqlstr = concat('update celle set needed = (select sum(',col_name,') from quadri) where cellaname = ', char(39),col_name,char(39),';'); 
        insert into debug_table (msg) values(@sqlstr);
        prepare stmt from @sqlstr;
        execute stmt ;
        deallocate prepare stmt;
end loop;
close cur1;
end $$
delimiter ;

truncate table debug_table;
call `AggiornaCelle`();
select * from debug_table;
select * from celle;

MariaDB [sandbox]> select * from debug_table;
+----+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+
| id | msg                                                                                      | MSG2 |
+----+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+
|  1 | update celle set needed = (select sum(SBR_750) from quadri) where cellaname = 'SBR_750'; | NULL |
|  2 | update celle set needed = (select sum(b10C) from quadri) where cellaname = 'b10C';       | NULL |
|  3 | update celle set needed = (select sum(TGI) from quadri) where cellaname = 'TGI';         | NULL |
+----+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> select * from celle;
+-----------+--------+-------+
| CELLANAME | NEEDED | READY |
+-----------+--------+-------+
| SBR_750   |      3 |    12 |
| b10C      |      2 |    10 |
| TGI       |      1 |     5 |
+-----------+--------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The debug_table only exists so that I can check the update statements.

Comment: FANTASTIC! Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

As per **[documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html)**

> set @s='update celle set needed=(select sum(?) from quadri) where cellaname=?';

You are supposed to pass two argument.

```
execute stmt using @NC;
```

should be or something similar

```
execute stmt using @NC, @NC;
```

`@NC` would be same as you are trying to update a row in `celle`, which is same as column name in `quadri` table.

Comment: Thanks. No more error but the sum result is wrong: 0

Comment: @MassimoGriffani I have updated the post, there were issue in your SQL. Let me know, if your problem solved

Comment: the column from which I want to extract the sum is also variable

Comment: @MassimoGriffani let us know, if your problem was solved

Comment: Tomorrow I will do

Comment: In this case is the same name, so `using @NC, @NC;`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I didn't get you. Since, value would be different for both placeholder

Comment: should be the same `SBR_750`, first is a fieldname for the SUM, then is row key for the update

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza ahhh.. I didn't see the data.  Exactly. :D. Updated, thanks for let me know.

Comment: Hey Ravi, I try several way to make it work but couldn't. Please take a look http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/284837/1  The only way was hardcoding the fieldname on the `SUM` otherwise get 0 as result.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Yes, even I thought so. I'm not in touch with mysql nowadays. But, I think, you are correct. I will update my post